# X11 forwarding between Debian and Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I like to use a browser on my Raspberry PI from my Debian Wheezy using SSH with X11 forwarding. I found that X11 forwarding is enabled by default in Raspian and also xauth is installed. Then I try

```
ssh -X pi@192.168.178.22
```

And get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/xauth: file /home/pi/.XAuthority dows not exist
```

What do I have to write into the file? Or what to do else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the message is perfectly right if you login the first time like this and .Xauthority does not exist. File is created then. The second time you login the message will not show up again.

Comment: Worked and I could start midori remote ...